# Batch delete | from a txt file

Tags: batch-file, pipe, text-files

I need to delete "|" from a .txt file.
It is supposed to be ^| in:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set INTEXTFILE=buffer.txt
set OUTTEXTFILE=test_out.txt
set SEARCHTEXT=^|
set REPLACETEXT=
set OUTPUTLINE=

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
SET string=%%A
SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!

echo !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
)
del %INTEXTFILE%
rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%
```

but it doesn't work
the current answer is: string:

i have also tried "|" and \| .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotes are required here, to avoid that the parser tries to handle the pipe character.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set INTEXTFILE=buffer.txt
set OUTTEXTFILE=test_out.txt
set "SEARCHTEXT=|"
set "REPLACETEXT="
set OUTPUTLINE=

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
  SET "string=%%A"
  SET "modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!"

  echo(!modified!
) > %OUTTEXTFILE%
del %INTEXTFILE%
rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%
```